# Airflow s3 list and copy files from one bucket to another bucket

Tags: python, airflow

New to Airflow here. I am trying to do few things to get my self comfortable with Airflow. As part of this, I tried to list all the files in a s3 bucket and copy them one by one to another bucket.

Here

```
    from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import Variable
import logging
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.s3 import S3ListOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.s3 import S3CopyObjectOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 2, 16),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_success': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'schedule': "@daily"
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='myFirstDag',
    start_date=datetime(2023, 5, 15),
    default_args= default_args,
    catchup=False
)    

@dag.task()
def print_objects(objects):
    print("All Keys", objects)
    last_task = None
    for key in objects:
        print("Current key", key)
        s3Copy = S3CopyObjectOperator(
        task_id= key,
        source_bucket_key=key,
        dest_bucket_key=key,
        source_bucket_name="s3-bukcet-for-airflow-in",
        dest_bucket_name="s3-bukcet-for-airflow-out",
        aws_conn_id="vivek_aws",
        dag=dag
        )
        if last_task:
            last_task >> s3Copy
        last_task = s3Copy               

list_bucket = S3ListOperator(
    task_id='list_files_in_bucket',
    bucket='s3-bukcet-for-airflow-in',
    aws_conn_id='vivek_aws'
)
print_objects(list_bucket.output)
```

You can see the logs it is looping through the files that I have in bucket. However it is not copying the files

> [2023-05-16, 15:29:41 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1507} INFO - Exporting the
> following env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
> AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=myFirstDag AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=print_objects
> AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-05-16T15:29:35.336231+00:00
> AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
> AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2023-05-16T15:29:35.336231+00:00
> [2023-05-16, 15:29:41 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} INFO - All Keys
> ['my-document-2.txt', 'my-document.txt'] [2023-05-16, 15:29:41 UTC]
> {logging_mixin.py:137} INFO - Current key my-document-2.txt
> [2023-05-16, 15:29:41 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} INFO - Current key
> my-document.txt [2023-05-16, 15:29:41 UTC] {python.py:177} INFO -
> Done. Returned value was: None

Answer (score 1):

For some reason S3CopyObjectOperator also didn't work for me. So I was able to resolve my issue with s3Hooks' copy_object() method. It should work seamlessly.

```
s3_conn_id = configuration['AWS_CONNECTION_ID']
s3_hook = S3Hook(s3_conn_id)
s3_hook.copy_object(
    source_bucket_name=source_bucket,
    source_bucket_key=file,
    dest_bucket_name=dest_bucket,
    dest_bucket_key=dest_key_file
)
```

Comment: It works for me when I am trying to copy a single file. However if I am trying to get all files and then copy one by one then it is not working

Comment: use it in a loop for each file, I had no other option and had to do this way and it works